# List of all modules implementing a behaviour in elixir

Tags: elixir

What could be the shortest possible way to get a list of all the modules implementing a behaviour?

e.g.

```
defmodule X do
  @callback foo()
end

defmodule A do
  @behaviour X
  def foo() do
    "hello"
  end
end

defmodule B do
  @behaviour X
  def foo() do
    "world"
  end
end
```

I would like to get a list as `[A,B]`. I tried loading all the modules and then filtering using the key attribute `behaviour` but I think it's going to be very slow. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no better way.  Behaviours are not indexed in any way, as they are a compile-time feature used to check that all required callback functions have been defined.  So something like this is as good as it gets:

```
for {module, _} <- :code.all_loaded(),
    X in (module.module_info(:attributes)[:behaviour] || []) do
        module
end
```

Answer (score 4):

To continue on the solution @legoscia provided.
There may be a case where you are implementing more than 1 behaviour per module, in such case something like this:

```
for {module, _} <- :code.all_loaded(),
    __MODULE__ in (module.module_info(:attributes)
                   |> Keyword.get_values(:behaviour)
                   |> List.flatten()) do
  module
end
```

Should be used as Keyword lists can have duplicated keys and accessing them directly won't return the desired result.

Thanks @legoscia!

Answer (score 2):

I found out another way of doing this, since `:code.all_loaded()` was not working for me. Instead I use `:application.get_key/2` which is more specific:

```
case :application.get_key(:my_app, :modules) do
      {:ok, modules} ->
        modules
        |> Enum.filter(fn module -> (module.module_info(:attributes)[:behaviour] || []) |> Enum.member?(MyBehaviour) end)

      error -> {:error, error}
    end
```

This did the trick for me, hopefully it helps someone else also.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach is to extract module attributes directly from the `.beam` files. It should extract behaviours from all modules, that your Elixir instance knows about. It extracts attributes from library modules too.

```
defmodule BehaviourMapping do
  @behaviour_mapping_key __MODULE__
  @mapping_not_found :not_found

  def recompute_mapping do
    behaviours_by_module =
      :code.all_available()
      |> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 1))
      |> Task.async_stream(:beam_lib, :chunks, [[:attributes]], ordered: false)
      |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn
        {:ok, {:ok, {module, [attributes: attrs]}}}, acc ->
          case Keyword.get_values(attrs, :behaviour) do
            [] -> acc
            behaviours -> Map.put(acc, module, List.flatten(behaviours))
          end

        _, acc ->
          acc
      end)

    behaviours_by_module =
      case Code.ensure_compiled(:cover) do
        {:module, compiled_module} ->
          for module <- compiled_module.modules(),
              into: behaviours_by_module do
            behaviours =
              module.__info__(:attributes)
              |> Keyword.get_values(:behaviour)
              |> List.flatten()

            {module, behaviours}
          end

        _ ->
          behaviours_by_module
      end

    result =
      for {module, behaviours} <- behaviours_by_module,
          behaviour <- behaviours,
          reduce: %{} do
        mapping ->
          Map.update(
            mapping,
            behaviour,
            MapSet.new([module]),
            &MapSet.put(&1, module)
          )
      end

    :persistent_term.put(@behaviour_mapping_key, result)
    result
  end

  def mapping do
    case :persistent_term.get(@behaviour_mapping_key, @mapping_not_found) do
      @mapping_not_found ->
        recompute_mapping()

      result ->
        result
    end
  end
end
```

The function `BehaviourMapping.recompute_mapping/0` returns a map, where keys are the behaviour modules, and values are [MapSets](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.15/MapSet.html) of modules, that implement this behaviour. It also uses [persistent_term](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/persistent_term) to cache the computation results.

The function `BehaviourMapping.mapping/0` uses tries to take results from persistent term or recomputes the mapping.

When Erlang (and Elixir) cover-compiles modules, they are marked as `:modified`, so `:beam_lib.chunks` is not able to load and extract attributes from them. The loop related to `:cover.modules()` extracts attributes from such files too.

If your project has Elixir version at least 1.4.0, then you can speed up recomputation with [Task.async_stream/5](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/Task.html#async_stream/5) function.
I have tested it on my machine and it provided about 30% performance gains for 2000+ available sources.